# How do I clean up linseed oil?

Tags: cleaning

One of the many things I loathe about our kitchen cabinets is that although they're stained to a mahogany tone dark brown, the undersides of the uppers (which are visible from our kitchen table) are rough birch plywood. I had the bright idea to use some imitation gold leaf that I've had forever to beautify my breakfast vista. I turns out I should possibly have done more research or at least read the instructions on the size, because I made a mess of it. On the upside, you can only see it if you're sitting at the kitchen table. It has a nice glow, though, and I'm slowly figuring out how to salvage it.

But: the size is a mix of linseed, tung, mineral spirits and petroleum distillate. What should I use to clean my brush off? Can I bag the brush so I can keep using it for a few days or is that dangerous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bagging is fine: the lack of oxygen will keep it from spontanously combusting.

Mineral spirit will clean it.